# don't want to create a write protected

Tags: c

I have this assignment, part of it needs to create some files that have the name xNNNNNN, where NNNNNN is replaced by a random six-digit number and the files should be created in the random order in which their names are generated, I've already do that but the problem is that the files I get is a **write protected** but I want them to be **write only**, what I'm doing wrong ?? is it related to the flags or something else ?

here is what I write :

```
  int file;
  int fileName;
  int counter;
  char str1[5];
  char str2[5];
  int fileNum = atoi(argv[2]);

  for (counter = 0; counter < fileNum ; counter++)
  {
     fileName = rand() % 900000 + 100000; 

     sprintf (str1, "%d", fileName); //write the value of r as a string in str
     sprintf (str2, "%s%s", "x", str1);
     printf ("%s\n" ,str2); 

     file = open (str2, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH); 
     if (file != -1)
     {
         //do something 
     } 
  }
```

Comment: I believe it is "fopen()" not "open()", also there is a "FILE*" type that is usually used to hold file pointers

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson: It's the POSIX API.  Quite standard.

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson: `fopen()` returns a `FILE*`. `open()` returns an `int` that represents a file descriptor. The latter is perfectly valid.

Comment: Are you mixing up open flags and file permissions? A file opened as write only has nothing to do with the file permissions being write only.

Answer (score 4):

You want them to be write-only, but you pass read-only permissions to `open()`:

```
file = open (str2, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

The permissions here are `S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH`.  The `O_WRONLY` flag is for permissions on the file descriptor itself, not permissions on the created file.

This does what you want:

```
file = open(str2, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0222);
```

Note that `0222 = S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH`.  I personally find octal much easier to read, but you may prefer the other notation.

### Note about umask

Permissions on created files will be modified by removing bits set in the umask.  If you really need the permissions to be 0222, and not, say, 0200, there are two ways:

#### Change the permissions after opening the file

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int fdes;
fdes = open(str2, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0222);
if (fdes < 0) abort();
fchmod(fdes, 0222);
```

#### Change the process umask

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

mode_t saved_umask;
int fdes;
saved_umask = umask(0);
fdes = open(str2, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0222);
umask(saved_umask);
```

Comment: hey,
thanx for answer, but I still have the write protected files, I have tried to use the 777 as a permision but it also doesn't work, at this point I just prefere anything that will make this code works.

Comment: @MIQasaimeh: Really?  When I try it I get files that are write-only.  What are the exact permissions on the files you created (use `ls -l`)?  Are you okay with obeying umask, or do you want to override it?

Comment: You said you wanted "write-only" -- `rwxr-xr-x` is not write-only.